# Mutex - counting occurrences of a char in files using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Hi I am writing a code for counting the number of occurrences of a certain letter inside one or more files using thread. I have to use one thread for each file e use a mutex to modify the global total.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct _CharFile{

    char c;
    char *fileName;

} CharFile;

pthread_mutex_t count = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int sum = 0;

void *CountFile(void *threadarg);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    pthread_t threads[argc-2];
    int chck, t;
    CharFile cf;

    if (argc <= 2){

        perror("Wrong inputs: need to select a letter and one or more files\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    } else if (argc > 51) {

        perror("Too many files\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    for ( t=0 ; t<argc-2 ; t++ ){

        cf.c = argv[1][0];
        cf.fileName = (char *)argv[t + 2];

        chck = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, CountFile, (void *) &cf);
        if (chck){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", chck);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    printf("%lld occurrences of the letter %c in %lld threads\n", (long long)sum, argv[1][0], (long long)argc-2);

    return 0;
}

void *CountFile(void *threadarg){

    FILE *in;
    CharFile *cf;
    char c;
    int counter = 0;

    cf = (CharFile *) threadarg;
    in = fopen(cf->fileName, "r");

    if (in == NULL){

        perror("Error opening the file!\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);

    }

    while (fscanf(in, "%c", &c) != EOF){

        if(c == cf->c){

            counter ++;

        }

    }

    fclose(in);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&count);
    sum += counter;
    printf("%d sum value, %d counter value \n", sum, counter);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I don't know where is wrong but using some files that I have with bunch of letters the results are strange.

Running this line `./a.out f file1.in lorem.txt notes.txt` twice I get these results:

```
4 sum value, 4 counter value 
9 sum value, 5 counter value 
13 sum value, 4 counter value 
13 occurrences of the letter f in 3 threads

4 sum value, 4 counter value 
8 sum value, 4 counter value 
12 sum value, 4 counter value 
12 occurrences of the letter f in 3 threads
```

While if I run a simpler command line with only one file the counting is correct, i.e. `./a.out f file1.in`

```
5 sum value, 5 counter value 
5 occurrences of the letter f in 1 threads
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statments

Comment: regarding: `cf.fileName = (char *)argv[t + 2];` All entries in `argv[]` are char pointers, so no need to cast it.  Casting the `argv[]` entry just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(in, "%c", &c) != EOF){`  there are other reasons for the fscanf() to fail.  Suggest only assuring success, as in: `while (fscanf(in, "%c", &c) == 1){`

Comment: regarding: `if (chck){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", chck);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`  1) It is not a good idea to exit without first 'pthread_join()` any existing threads. 2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a system function should also output the related text for that error.   Suggest using: `perror( "pthread_create failed" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be here:

```
for ( t=0 ; t<argc-2 ; t++ ){

    cf.c = argv[1][0];
    cf.fileName = (char *)argv[t + 2];

    chck = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, CountFile, (void *) &cf);
    if (chck){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", chck);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}
```

You pass all threads a pointer to the same variable (i.e. `cf`). After passing the pointer to the first thread, you change the value of `cf` and pass a pointer to it to the second thread and so.

Therefore it may happen that the main loop changes `cf` before the "just stared" thread reads its value, i.e. the thread may open another file than intended.

Make sure that each thread get its own `cf` by changing `cf` to an array, i.e. one element per thread.

Comment: Yes that's was the problem. Thank you a lot

Comment: @ThomasGeorge One way is to make an array of `struct _CharFile` like `struct _CharFile ch[argc-2]` and then do like `cf[t].fileName = (char *)argv[t + 2]; chck = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, CountFile, &cf[t]); ...`